# Best treatment for dishwasher rollers that use metal screws

Tags: dishwasher, rust-proofing

My dishwasher roller wheels are plastic and have started to fail.  I bought replacements, but another of the original plastic ones has started to fail.  When I went to look I saw that the replacements used metal parts to hold the wheels in place (see pictures) rather than purely plastic.  Now those metal parts have rusted badly.

Before I put more of these metal-based replacements into the dishwasher, can I treat the parts with rustoleum or some kind of [plastic](https://plastidip.com/our-products/rerack/) covering to make them last longer?  Is the rustoleum dishwasher safe?

The previous replacement rollers haven't been in there for even 1 year, probably about 9 months.

[image: Replacement rollers with corroding parts after 9-12 months]
[image: New replacement rollers with metal parts removed. 1 screw, 1 washer, 1 head]

[image: Metal parts, side 1]

[image: Metal parts, side 2]

Comment: clear nail polish is a good cheap and available material for conformal coatings.

Answer (score 1):

From your picture, it looks like just the washer is rusting. Replace the washers with stainless steel washers to prevent rusting. You can source these from anywhere you can find a stainless washer of the appropriate size.

It appears that the screw and screw-post are not rusting, indicating that they're made out of stainless steel.

Not sure why they would have made the parts out of different materials, but it seems they have - it's probably cheaper this way.

Comment: I hadn't posted pictures of the screw, just the barrel/post and the washer.  I will post new pictures.  Does look like the washer has taken the biggest brunt, certainly.

Comment: Ah, yes, I see that the whole kit-and-kaboodle is rusting out there. Source stainless (or brass as Harper recommends) from wherever you can get matching parts and roll your own kit.

Answer (score 0):

Those things are called "sex bolts", though apparently in the modern age, we're supposed to call them **"binding barrels"**.

They are available in [a variety of materials](https://www.mcmaster.com/sex-bolts/).  If you don't like the corrosion, stainless steel or brass are pretty safe bets.   You'll want to be dealing with outfits who are insanely great at oddball fasteners, such as McMaster-Carr or (less so) Grainger or (weirdly, even less so) Fastenal.

The washers are just washers, but you gotta watch dimensions.